# How to return value from function running by QThread and Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

Please explain how do we send/receive data from Thread managed by Queue....

First I subclass 'QThread' defining its `run()` method which is started when `QThread`'s`.start()` is called:

```
class SimpleThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, queue, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)      
        self.queue=queue        
    def run(self):
        while True:
            arg=self.queue.get() 
            self.fun(arg)    
            self.queue.task_done()
    def fun(self, arg):
        for i in range (3):
            print 'fun: %s'%i
            self.sleep(1)
        return arg+1
```

Then I declare two Thread instances (so only two CPU cores are taken) sending `self.queue` instance as an argument.

```
self.queue=queue.Queue()
for i in range(2):
    thread=SimpleThread(self.queue)
    thread.start()
```

Now if I understand it correctly `thread.start()` is not starting anything. The real "start" happens only when I call `queue.put()`:

```
for arg in [1,2,3]: self.queue.put(arg)
```

This last line is what makes a "real" call. Aside from creating and starting *Queue item* `put()` allows to save any arbitrary value to each *Queue item*. `.put()` does several things at once: it creates, it starts, it moves the processing through the Queue and it allows to place a variable "inside" of the queue item (which later can be retrieved from inside of the function-processor: using Queue item's '.get()` method).

But how do  I return the value from `fun()` function. A "regular" `fun()`'s  `return resultValue` doesn't work. And I can't use self.queue.put() method since this method aside from storing a data "creates" a new queue item...

## EDITED LATER:

Here is slightly tweaked code (copy/pasted from another post) showing an approach on how to return a value from completed Thread. I am not sure if the the approach used here would work with QThread... please correct me if I am wrong:

```
import os, sys
import threading
import Queue

def callMe(incomingFun, daemon=False):
    def execute(_queue, *args, **kwargs):
        result=incomingFun(*args, **kwargs)
        _queue.put(result)

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        _queue=Queue.Queue()
        _thread=threading.Thread(target=execute, args=(_queue,)+args, kwargs=kwargs)
        _thread.daemon=daemon
        _thread.start()
        _thread.result_queue=_queue        
        return _thread

    return wrap

@callMe
def localFunc(x):
    import time
    x = x + 5
    time.sleep(5)
    return x

thread=localFunc(10)

# this blocks, waiting for the result
result = thread.result_queue.get()
print result
```

Comment: You almost never should derive from QThread. You can use signals and slots to deliver messages from worker threads to the main thread. But [Qt Concurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html) is much more convenient your task.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I don't think `QtConcurrent` is available in any of Qt's Python bindings.

Comment: First let's clarify on how we handle a return value from `fun()` function. And then we can discuss what should and shouldn't be derived.

Comment: Do you want `SimpleThread` to run forever in the background, or should it end after you've passed some arbitrary number of values to it?

Comment: `SimpleThread` should end like a normal function when it is done. The reason I span to 'QThread' process is to break the link between GUI and the process itself (so Qt GUI doesn't get "frozen" while the procesess or calculation or downloads and etc) happening at the backgound. So all those SimpleThreads should die after they are done.

Comment: Do you absolutely need `QThread` for this? This task would be really well suited to `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`/`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Generally, you create a second return queue for results.

Comment: I am not ready for mutliprocessing module. It is hard to setup. And I won't be having Qt signals and it needs a different setup approach for different OS platforms (Win and OSX).

Comment: @Sputnix `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` would look exactly the same no matter what platform you're using. And it uses threads, not multiple processes.

Comment: @tdelaney: please show an example how do we setup a second queue to handle the return value.

Comment: @Sputnix What are you going to do with the results when you get them? It's an important factor in deciding how to handle the return values.

Comment: At very first the returned value will be used to populate widgets with the data.

Comment: @Sputnix The issue with your edited example is it will block the main thread while you wait for the workers to complete. You don't want to do that, because that will block Qt's event loop.

Comment: @Sputnix Also, you're using `range(1, MAX_CORES)`, where `MAX_CORES` is 2. That's only creating one thread. I think you really just want `range(MAX_CORES)`, so that 2 threads are created.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer, I was out for ahile... I like @dano's answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In normal circumstances you'd use a result queue to send results back, and then have some other thread running that waits for the results:

```
class SimpleThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, queue, result_queue, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)      
        self.queue=queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            arg=self.queue.get() 
            self.fun(arg)    
            self.queue.task_done()

    def fun(self, arg):
        for i in range (3):
            print 'fun: %s'%i
            self.sleep(1)
        self.result_queue.put(arg+1)

def handle_results(result_queue):
   while True:
       result = result_queue.get()
       print("Got result {}".format(result))
```

Main thread:

```
self.queue=queue.Queue()
self.result_queue = queue.Queue()

result_handler = threading.Thread(target=handle_results, self.result_queue)
for i in range(2):
    thread=SimpleThread(self.queue, self.result_queue)
    thread.start()
```

Doing it this way will keep you from blocking the GUI's event loop while you wait for the results. Here's what the equivalent would look like with `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import time


def fun(arg):
    for i in range (3):
        print 'fun: %s'%i
        time.sleep(1)
    return arg+1

def handle_result(result):
   print("got result {}".format(result))

pool = ThreadPool(2)
pool.map_async(fun, [1,2,3], callback=handle_result)
```

Which is a lot simpler. It internally creates a result handling thread, which will automatically call `handle_result` for you when `fun` completes.

That said, you're using `QThread`, and you want the results to update GUI widgets, so you really want your results to be sent back to the main thread, not to a result handling thread. In that case, it makes sense to use Qt's signaling system, so that you can safely update the GUI when you receive the result:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
import Queue as queue

class ResultObj(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

class SimpleThread(QtCore.QThread):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, queue, callback, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)      
        self.queue = queue
        self.finished.connect(callback)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            arg = self.queue.get() 
            if arg is None: # None means exit
                print("Shutting down")
                return
            self.fun(arg)    

    def fun(self, arg):
        for i in range(3):
            print 'fun: %s' % i
            self.sleep(1)
        self.finished.emit(ResultObj(arg+1))


class AppWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppWindow, self).__init__()
        mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)  
        button = QtGui.QPushButton('Process')
        button.clicked.connect(self.process)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button)

    def handle_result(self, result):
        val = result.val
        print("got val {}".format(val))
        # You can update the UI from here.

    def process(self):
        MAX_CORES=2
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        self.threads = []
        for i in range(MAX_CORES):
            thread = SimpleThread(self.queue, self.handle_result)
            self.threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()  

        for arg in [1,2,3]:
            self.queue.put(arg)

        for _ in range(MAX_CORES): # Tell the workers to shut down
            self.queue.put(None)

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = AppWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output when the button is pushed:

```
fun: 0
 fun: 0
fun: 1
 fun: 1
fun: 2
 fun: 2
fun: 0
got val 2
got val 3
Shutting down
fun: 1
fun: 2
Shutting down
got val 4
```

Comment: Great example code! Thanks again. One of the best resources I have learned in a long time! Thanks for educating!

Comment: in your last example, there is a typo s/finshed/finished to make it work

Comment: i need this answer in pyqt5

Comment: @lone_coder It looks like `pyqtSignal` is still there in pyqt5, so it should be straightforward to adapt this answer.

Comment: @dano. yeah, I've already figured it out thanks tho!